# Grouped table view -- section spacing

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In a grouped table view can I control the spacing between two sections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implement [`tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) or [`tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: So that means changing the section header height will change the spacing between two section... Is this understanding correct?

Comment: yeah, and as it is a delegate-method, u r free to define the rules, that will calculate the height. ie, u might do want to give the first section-header 10px of height but all other 30px. u r free to do so by simple `if (section == 0) return 10.0; return 30.0`

Answer (score 4):

Agree with 'viking'.. If you are still having troubles, I have noticed that if you create the table through IB it automatically creates a table header/footer section.  If you go into the measurments(in IB) and decrease/increase the height of each section you will see the spacing between grouped sections change.

Answer (score 3):

`tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` and `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:`

together these control the space in between sections of a grouped UITableView. You cannot return 0, it will use the default value if you do, so use a small float (0.01) to reduce the space to almost nothing.

Comment: Excellent call out that returning 0 will apparently result in `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` being used (even though that constant is defined to `-1.0f` when I checked).