# How to modify the font size for the text in a grouped header of a table view?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm working witha simple tableview but I need to modify the font size for the text in the group header.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229613/grouped-table-view-section-spacing) question on stackoverflow eferencing the tableview methods to override but I'm looking for an example of how I might modify the actual headers font size once I implement this method

Note: I'm able to modify the height of the header itself using interface builder but the font size appears to require some objective-c to modify this

Thank you in advance

**Edit**

here is what I have so far -it's not throwing an exception but the header itself doesn't show the text or font size I set on the label itself

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView* x = tableView.tableHeaderView;
    UILabel* y = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 310, 0)];
    y.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
    y.text = @"ha";
    [x addSubview:y];
    [y release];

    return x;
}
```

Comment: see my revisions below in response to your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header for a table may be set to any subclass of `UIView`. In particular, you can create a `UILabel`, set the text with your desired font size, then make the label the `headerView`.

---

Three potential problems with your edit:

1. Did you remember to implement `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`?
2. The height of your `UILabel` is currently `0`.
3. When this method is called, `tableView.tableHeaderView` may not yet be defined.

My approach would be to declare `UILabel *headerLabel` and then add this to `viewDidLoad`:

```
headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 310, 15)];
headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
headerLabel.text = @"Testing";
```

Then have

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 15.0;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return headerLabel;
}
```

Comment: So I would do this in the method - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {}

Comment: You can create the label(s) anywhere you like (`viewDidLoad` is a good choice) and then return them from the method you mention.

Comment: thanks for the exact answer I was looking for! The only issue I ran into is that I couldn't create a single label and reuse it like you mentioned. I had to re-create it each time inside the "viewForHeaderInSection" method